# Is there a way of iterating through a specific XML tag in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri, rexml

Is it possible to iterate over a specific XML tag in Ruby? In my case I want iterate over the `desc` tag in the following XML code:

```
<desc>
     <id>2408</id>
     <who name="Joe Silva">joe@silva.com</who>
     <when>Today</when>
     <thetext>Hello World</thetext>
</desc>
<desc>
     <id>2409</id>
     <who name="Joe Silva2">joe2@silva.com</who>
     <when>Future</when>
     <thetext>Hello World Again</thetext>
</desc>
```

So far, here is the code I use:

```
xml_doc = agent.get("www.somewhere.com/file.xml")
document = REXML::Document.new(xml_doc.body);

# iterate over desc here
```

I want to iterate over each `desc` tags so that I get the following output:

```
commentid : 2408
name : Joe Silva
who : joe@silva.com
bug_when : Today
thetext : Hello World 

commentid : 2409
name : Joe Silva2
who : joe2@silva.com
bug_when : Future
thetext : Hello World Again
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is this *NOT* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157224/how-to-get-the-attributes-of-an-xml-tag-using-ruby-with-rexml?

Comment: Use XPath to iterate over a *node list*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri example that includes the `name` attribute for the `who` node:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.XML '
<root>
  <desc>
     <id>2408</id>
     <who name="Joe Silva">joe@silva.com</who>
     <when>Today</when>
     <thetext>Hello World</thetext>
  </desc>
  <desc>
    <id>2409</id>
     <who name="Joe Silva2">joe2@silva.com</who>
     <when>Future</when>
     <thetext>Hello World Again</thetext>
  </desc>
</root>
'

doc.css("desc").each do |desc|
  puts "commentid : #{desc.css("id").text}"
  puts "name : #{desc.css("who").attribute("name")}"  
  puts "who : #{desc.css("who").text}"
  puts "bug_when : #{desc.css("when").text}"
  puts "the text : #{desc.css("thetext").text}"  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd also recommend using the [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) gem. Something like this ought to work:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

# fetch and parse the document
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('www.somewhere.com/file.xml'))

# search with css selectors
puts doc.at('desc id').text

# search by xpath
puts doc.at_xpath('//desc/id').text

# to iterate over a specific tag
doc.css('desc').each do |tag|
  puts tag.css('id').text
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Instead of `doc.css('desc id').first` use `doc.at('desc id')`. Instead of `xpath('//desc/id').first` use `at_xpath(...)`.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that one. I've updated my answer.